# JSON file processing with a different structure

Tags: java, android, json

I have an android app (Java) that processes an API from te web.

Currently the app is processing a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "name1", 
        "email": "email1", 
        "phone": "1234567890"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        ETC...
```

I need to process another JSON file but it has a different structure:

```
{
    "contacts": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "name1", 
            "email": "email1", 
            "phone": "1234567890", 
            "level1": {
                "level2": {
                    "level3": 3, 
                }
            }, 
            "last_updated": 20180712
        }, 
        "2": {
            ETC...
```

How do I process this second JSON file by adjusting the below code?

```
    if (jsonSource != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonSource);
            JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayData.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject contacts = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = contacts.getString("id");
                String name = contacts.getString("name");
                String email = contacts.getString("email");
                String phone = contacts.getString("phone");

                HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
                values.put("id", id);
                values.put("name", name);
                values.put("email, email);
                values.put("phone, phone);
                contactList.add(values);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to retrieve JSON file from URL");
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks, that inside first json you have "contacts" as array of objects, and inside second one you have "contacts" as object. Inside it you have other objects, simplified version looks like this:

```
"contacts": [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]
"contacts": {
    "1": {...}, 
    "2": {...},
    "3": {...}
}
```

So, the only option you have is to check manually is "contacts" array or object, and based on it change your code.
It would look like this:

```java
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonSource);
if (jsonObject.get("contacts") instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject contactsJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("contacts");
    for (Iterator<String> it = contactsJson.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String key = it.next();
        JSONObject contactJson = contactsJson.getJSONObject(key);
        // your code to process contact item
    }
} else {
    // Your code to process every contact item
}
```